# Prove this derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> If $$y=1+\frac{x_{1}}{x-x_1}+\frac{x_2x}{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)}+\frac{x_3x^2}{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)}+...$$
> upto $n+1$ terms, then prove that
> $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}\left[\frac{x_1}{x_1-x}+\frac{x_2}{x_2-x}+...+\frac{x_n}{x_n-x}\right]$$

I tried to make the denominators the same but had no progress in the proof as the expression came back to the given condition. I am unable to think of other ways of proving this. Please help. Thank You!

Comment: Did you try induction?

Comment: For your intuition - Personally, my take on problems like this is that Math Lover's approach is like hanging a painting in an art gallery, while induction, as suggested by Soumyadwip Chanda is the tried and true paint by numbers approach which will often get the job done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$y = 1+\frac{x_{1}}{x-x_1}+\frac{x_2x}{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)}+\frac{x_3x^2}{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)}+...\frac{x_3x^{n-1}}{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)...(x-x_n)}$

Please note

$1+\frac{x_{1}}{x-x_1} = \frac{x}{x-x_1}$

$1+\frac{x_{1}}{x-x_1}+\frac{x_2x}{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)} = \frac{x}{x-x_1} + \frac{x_2x}{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)} = \frac{x^2}{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)}$

So you finally get

$y = \frac{x^n}{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)..(x-x_n)}$

$ \ln y = n \ln x -  \ln (x-x_1) - \ln(x-x_2).. - \ln(x-x_n)$

$\frac{1}{y} \frac {dy}{dx} = \frac{n}{x} - \frac{1}{x-x_1} - \frac{1}{x-x_2} - ...- \frac{1}{x-x_n}$

$\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{x} (n - \frac{x}{x-x_1} - \frac{x}{x-x_2} - ...- \frac{x}{x-x_n})$

$ = \frac {y}{x} (1 - \frac{x}{x - x_1} + 1 - \frac{x}{x - x_2} - ...+ 1 - \frac{x}{x - x_n})$

$ = \frac {y}{x} (- \frac{x_1}{x - x_1} - \frac{x_2}{x - x_2} - ...- \frac{x_n}{x - x_n})$

$ = \frac {y}{x} (\frac{x_1}{x_1 - x} + \frac{x_2}{x_2 - x} + ...+ \frac{x_n}{x_n - x})$

Comment: +1 elegant and nicely formatted